# java compare attribution in different ojbects

Tags: java, object

I am an java beginner,(forgive my bad English)I want to compare student objects which has (name, score). and return the student name with the highest score. 
    I have getScore and getName in my student class.

```
public String tallest() {

    //set a defaut value
    int score = 0;
    for(Student student: this.student) {
        // compare which student has highest score
        if(student.getScore() < score) {
            score = student.getScore();
            String name = ((String)student.getName());
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

another question is about how to return all student object with (name,score) that are above 80.

```
public ArraryList<student>goodStudent<int level> { 
  int level = 80;
  for(Student student: this.student) {
     if(student.getScore > 80) {
     (don't know how to do here >.<)   

   return list;
}
```

Comment: If you want the highest score you should check `if(student.getScore() > score) {` not `<`

Comment: As for the second you should create an empty list and add to it any student that has level >= from given level.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String tallest() {
    return Collections.max(students,
            Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getScore)).getName();
}

public List<Student> goodStudent(int level) {
    return student.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getScore() > level)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question, you can use java `Comparator`, build `ScoreComparator` that compare `Student` based on their scores. Then use `Collections.sort(students, new ScoreComprator())` sort the list and you can get the highest score from it(depends on how you sort it whether in increasing order or decresing order)

For 2nd question, you can instantiate another ArrayList, then iterate your list `students`, if `student.getScore() > 80` add it to the new create list.

Comment: Even though the OP says "compare student objects" he doesn't really compare them, but rather tries to "filter" them by score criteria

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help. Any question feel free to ask.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Student{
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Student(String name, int score){
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Student[] students = {new Student("Jhon", 78), new Student("Kevin", 90), new Student("Max", 100)};

    Student maxScore = GetMaxScore(students);
    System.out.println("Max Score:");
    System.out.println(maxScore.getScore());

    ArrayList<Student> studentsOverVal = GetScoreOverVal(students, 80);
    System.out.println("Students with score over 80: ");
    for(Student student: studentsOverVal) {
       System.out.println(student.getName());
        }

    }

    private static Student GetMaxScore(Student[] students) {
    Student max = students[0];
    for(Student student: students) {
        if(student.getScore() > max.getScore())
            max = student;

        }
    return max;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Student> GetScoreOverVal(Student[] students, int val) {
    ArrayList<Student> overVal = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Student student: students) {
        if(student.getScore() >= val)
            overVal.add(student);
        }
    return overVal;
    }
```

}